# Advanced qooxdoo controller selection bindings?

Tags: qooxdoo

I need to enable a button only if at least an item is selected, and additionally I want to bind the count of selected items.

Using converter functions when applying the bindings I came to the following solution ([run in qooxdoo Playground](http://www.qooxdoo.org/devel/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22%252F%252F%2520Multi-selection%2520with%2520%253CCtrl%253E%2520enabled.%2520Click%2520the%2520button%2520to%2520clear%2520the%2520selection.%250A%250Aroot%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250Aroot.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.VBox())%253B%250A%250Avar%2520model%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.data.Array(%255B'one'%252C%2520'two'%252C%2520'three'%252C%2520'four'%252C%2520'five'%255D)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520list%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.List().set(%257BselectionMode%253A%2520'multi'%257D)%253B%250Aroot.add(list)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520button%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button()%253B%250Abutton.addListener('execute'%252C%2520list.resetSelection%252C%2520list)%250Aroot.add(button)%253B%250A%250A%250A%252F****%2520Bindings%2520****%252F%250A%250Avar%2520controller%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.data.controller.List(model%252C%2520list)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Enable%2520button%2520when%2520there%2520is%2520at%2520least%2520one%2520list%2520element%2520selected%250Acontroller.bind('selection%255B0%255D'%252C%2520button%252C%2520'enabled'%252C%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520converter%253A%2520function%2520(data)%250A%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520(data)%2520%253F%2520true%2520%253A%2520false%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Label%2520button%2520with%2520amount%2520of%2520selected%2520list%2520items%250Acontroller.bind('selection'%252C%2520button%252C%2520'label'%252C%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520converter%253A%2520function%2520(data)%250A%2520%2520%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520data.length.toString()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)):

```js
// Multi-selection with <Ctrl> enabled. Click the button to clear the selection.

root = this.getRoot();
root.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox());

var model = new qx.data.Array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']);

var list = new qx.ui.form.List().set({selectionMode: 'multi'});
root.add(list);

var button = new qx.ui.form.Button();
button.addListener('execute', list.resetSelection, list)
root.add(button);

/**** Bindings ****/

var controller = new qx.data.controller.List(model, list);

// Enable button when there is at least one list element selected
controller.bind('selection[0]', button, 'enabled', {
   converter: function (data)
   {
      return (data) ? true : false;
   }
});

// Label button with amount of selected list items
controller.bind('selection', button, 'label', {
   converter: function (data)
   {
     return data.length.toString();
   }
});
```

It works, *but*:

Is there a better solution, ideally without converter functions?

I searched for properties like "isSelected" or "selection.length", to no avail. I want to understand the binding system and think I'm missing something...

Enabling/disabling button via events, without bindings, is even less elegant, and it requires the button to be disabled initially:

```js
controller.getSelection().addListener('change', function ()
{
   button.setEnabled(controller.getSelection().getLength() > 0)
}, this)
button.setEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have an *isSomethingSelected* flag, you will need some binding.

The *selection* is a *qx.data.Array*, so you can simplify your code a bit by just listening for *length* changes - either by binding with a *number* to *boolean* converter, or with a change listener:

```
controller.getSelection().addListener("changeLength", function(ev) {
  var length = ev.getData();
  button.set({
    enabled : length > 0,
    label : length.toString()
});
```

The latter makes sense if you want the number of selected items in the button. As you already stated, you'll need to disable the button initially in this case.